# Measuring voltage with a current pulse

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, batteries, current, battery-charging

I'm using an [MCP73831 battery charger IC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP73831-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20001984H.pdf).

In the battery detection section, on page 13, section 4.2 of the datasheet, it is mentioned that the Vbat pin sends a small amount of current which helps in detecting the presence or absence of the battery.

How is this achieved? I checked the internal function block diagram of the IC but was not able to understand how by sending a current out of the pin, the presence or absence of a battery is determined.
Normally, there will be a capacitor also connected in parallel to the battery across the Vbat pin and GND.

My understanding is that, the Vbat pin is an output pin and it can source current only. How can it become an input and sense the voltage rise/fall, thereby detecting the presence or absence of the battery?

Is this the only way to detect the presence/absence of a battery? In broad terms, can voltage be determined only by sending current?

Please help me understand this.

I assume this sensing is very different to determining the SoC of the battery which requires complex circuitry with MCUs.

Answer (score 0):

Vbat is an output, but it is also "looked at" by other circuitry inside the IC.

The red lines I've drawn on this block from the datasheet show where Vbat is used internally:

[image]

Vbat is an output, but the voltage on that pin can be measured internally by the IC and evaluated.

The section circled in red here can be used to disconnect the battery from the charge current:

[image]

The FETs by the "Direction Control" disconnect the battery from Vdd, then the 6µA current source in the upper left corner would be switched on.  The voltage on Vbat would be measured internally to see if the voltage rises due to the current source.  If it rises too much then there's no battery attached.  It it doesn't rise much (or at all) then there's a battery attached.

---

You don't normally need a current to measure the voltage.  The battery presence detection isn't looking for a simple voltage present on Vbat.  It is looking for something that absorbs current.

When the battery is present, there will be a voltage on Vbat.  There will also be a voltage on Vbat when the output capacitor is charged.

The current source is used to tell the difference between "battery attached" and "output capacitor is charged."

When the battery is attached, the µA current won't cause a rise in voltage - the battery will "soak it up."

When the battery is not attached, there will be a voltage on Vbat due to the charged capacitor.  The 6 µA current will cause that voltage to rise - the capacitor will continue to charge since the current source will continue to raise the voltage to maintain the current flow.

Detecting the state of charge (SoC) requires different circuitry.  I don't see that the MCP73831 does state of charge.  It changes the charging mode depending on the battery voltage and the charge current.  Section 4 of the datasheet describes the conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As already asked in the question, I had one other question and a clarification. 1. Do we always require a current to measure the voltage? And for clarification, the method described in the above datasheet on senses the presence or absence of the battery. For SoC determination, there needs to be much more complex circuitry right?

Answer (score 0):

> In the battery detection section, on page 13, section 4.2 of the datasheet, it is mentioned that the Vbat pin sends a small amount of current which helps in detecting the presence or absence of the battery.
>
> How is this achieved? I checked the internal function block diagram of the IC but was not able to understand how by sending a current out of the pin, the presence or absence of a battery is determined.

The battery can be modeled (very crudely) as an ideal voltage source \$V_{SOURCE}\$ that is connected in series with a very small resistance \$R_{BAT}\$ (the battery's internal impedance).  If you force a test current \$I_{TEST}\$ to flow through the battery—i.e., through the series path of \$R_{BAT}\$ and \$V_{SOURCE}\$, the voltage at the battery's terminals will be:

```
V_BAT = I_TEST * R_BAT + V_SOURCE
```

If the battery's internal resistance \$R_{BAT}\$ is very small, which it typically is, and if the test current \$I_{TEST}\$ is also very small (which it is, i.e., \$I_{TEST}=6 \,\mu\text{A}\$), then \$V_{BAT} \approx V_{SOURCE}\$.

Now note that \$V_{REG}\$ is the regulated voltage the IC applies to the battery's terminals when the charging cycle is operating in constant voltage (CV) mode.  If a battery is present, and if the IC is operating in CV mode, the battery's terminal voltage should be around

$$
V_{BAT} \approx V_{REG} + I_{TEST} \times R_{BAT}
$$

As before, if \$I_{TEST}\$ and \$R_{BAT}\$ are both very small, which they typically are, then

$$
V_{BAT} \approx V_{REG}
$$
So that's what the data sheet is saying on page 13 via this statement:

> If the voltage [VBAT] stays below V REG + 100 mV (typical), the device assumes that a battery is detected.

When a battery is not connected to the IC's \$V_{BAT}\$ pin, the IC's 6 μA test current is confined to the IC's internal circuitry. In this case the test current passes through some high value resistors (see the resistors located to the left of the amplifiers labeled PRECOND and CHARGE on the functional block diagram on page 2), which results in a voltage increase at \$V_{BAT}\$.  Specifically, the voltage at \$V_{BAT}\$ rises to (or more likely, rises above) \$V_{REG} + 100\,\text{mV}\$.  Consequently, the IC assumes a battery is not connected to the \$V_{BAT}\$ pin.

> My understanding is that, the Vbat pin is an output pin and it can source current only. How can it become an input and sense the voltage rise/fall, thereby detecting the presence or absence of the battery?

Look again at the functional block diagram on page 2. Note that the voltage on the \$V_{BAT}\$ output pin is constantly monitored (measured) by the amplifiers labeled **PRECOND**, **/CHARGE**, and **DETECTION CONTROL**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As already asked in the question, I had one other question and a clarification. 1. Do we always require a current to measure the voltage? And for clarification, the method described in the above datasheet on senses the presence or absence of the battery. For SoC determination, there needs to be much more complex circuitry right?

Comment: Also, when you say, "Now note that VREG
 is the regulated voltage the IC applies to the battery's terminals when the charging cycle is operating in constant voltage (CV) mode." , VREG is not provided by the battery charger IC when the IC is in Constant Current (CC) mode? Can you please clarify?

Comment: | VREG is not provided by the battery charger IC when the IC is in Constant Current (CC) mode? Can you please clarify? |  See Fig. 2-17 on page 9 and Fig. 4-1 on page 13.  On Fig. 2-17, the charging cycle starts out with a brief period of preconditioning, and then it switches to constant current (CC) mode (I_BAT = 100 mA). In this mode, the battery's terminal voltage V_BAT is determined by the charging current I_BAT flowing the battery and the battery's internal charge level.  At around t=90 min, the IC switches from CC mode to CV mode (V_BAT = V_REG ≈ 4.2 V).

Comment: So, before CV mode, that is , In CC mode, the battery voltage would obviously not be 4.2V. right?

Comment: Also, is sending a current pulse, the only way to measure a voltage? In general terms, that is the way?

Comment: |  So, before CV mode, that is , In CC mode, the battery voltage would obviously not be 4.2V. right? |  Correct.