# Is sending a current pulse to a device the only way to measure the voltage?

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, voltage-measurement

I'd just like to understand the ways in which the voltage of a device can be measured.

So far, I have read that the only way to measure the voltage is by sending a current pulse and then sensing the increase in current or sensing the voltage through some circuitry. Hence, I'd like to know whether there are any alternative ways for measuring the voltage or is it only by sending a current pulse?

Comment: You're going to have to define what you consider "the voltage of a device" to be. What kind of device?

Comment: Do you mean the voltage produced by the device (like a battery or solar cell or generator)? Or do you mean how you can determine the applied voltage that is needed to operate the device? In the first instance, a suitable voltmeter (or maybe an oscilloscope) is all that is required. In the second case, you would need to apply some sort of signal, like a voltage, and monitor the current as the voltage is varied, or in some cases a current would be applied while monitoring the voltage.

Comment: @GodJihyo, suppose the device is a battery?

Comment: How does the scope measure the voltage? Does it send a small current pulse to measure the voltage?

Comment: @Newbie No, a scope doesn't do that. There are several ways that scopes measure voltage depending on the type of scope (analog, digital). To measure a source of voltage does not required a pulse of current, you would only do something like that if you were measuring a voltage drop across a device that does not supply voltage such as a resistor or diode, and even then you wouldn't normally use a pulse, you would use a constant current source. I think you need to narrow your question down to what you want to measure and what you want to measure it with, otherwise it's too broad a question.

Comment: @GodJihyo, thank you for your comment. Yes, let me narrow down the question. But meanwhile, could you please tell on how the scope measures the voltage then?

Comment: @Newbie, you still have to define what "the voltage of a device" actually means. Until you have answered that question, and understand what that means, this discussion will go nowhere.

Comment: @BasK, voltage of a resistor I mean

Comment: A resistor doesn't have a voltage across it until a current flows through it.  You can't measure "the voltage" across a resistor by itself.  The resistor is part of a circuit.  The current in that case comes from the circuit.  If you want to measure the resistance of a resistor, then you can apply a known voltage, measure the current, then use Ohm's law to calculate the resistance.  Alternatively, you apply a known current, measure the voltage, then apply Ohm's law for the calculation.

Comment: @Newbie How do you define "voltage of a resistor"?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be in connection with [this earlier question,](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/659944/measuring-voltage-with-a-current-pulse) which was about how a battery charger IC detects that a battery is connected.

The MCP73831 mentioned in that question does, in fact, use a small current to see if a battery is connected.  It does so by measuring the voltage at the battery while a small current is applied - if the voltage rises, then there's no battery attached.

The current has nothing to do with measuring the voltage.  It is purely a trick to tell the difference between a battery (which may or may not be connected) and a capacitor (which is always attached.)  The IC is always measuring the voltage.  The current injection is used to force a change in the voltage to tell whether the voltage is from a battery (no voltage change when current is applied) or from a capacitor (relatively large voltage change when the current is applied.)

Voltmeters and oscilloscopes do **not** inject a current to measure voltage.  The current injection used by the MCP73831 is only to tell whether a battery is there or not.

---

Back in the old days, you measured voltage by measuring current - you had to draw a fairly large (milliamperes) current from the voltage source to determine the voltage.

A current flowing through a wire makes a magnetic field.  That magnetic field will cause the needle of a compass to move.

A voltmeter would have a coil with a known resistance.  When you connected it to a voltage source, a current proportional to the voltage would flow through the coil.  There was a needle attached to a small magnet that would move when current flowed through the coil.  More current = needle move more.  More current (given a fixed resistancr in the coil) meant a higher voltage.

Practical meters actually had a fixed magnet, a moving coil, and a separate resistor because it was easier to make them accurate.  [Have a look at the Wikipedia page on voltmeters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltmeter) for more details.

Modern methods of measuring voltage will usually use electrical effects in semiconductors.  That may be the current through the base of a bipolar junction transistor or the voltage on the gate of a field effect transistor.  It would also be possible to make a voltmeter using a Hall effect sensor to detect the magnetic field from the current like in the old moving coil meters - though I'm not sure it would be accurate with the very low currents used.

In nearly all cases, a voltmeter draws a small amount of current to measure the voltage.  Even an [electrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrometer) will draw a small current.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mention, "Voltmeters and oscilloscopes do not inject a current to measure voltage", then how do they measure the voltage?

Comment: Just as described above - they draw a teeny tiny current from the source being measured.

Comment: Please do read the wikipedia article.  It includes a lot of background information that you seem to be missing.

Comment: It may also help if you find a compass (the kind that points north and south, not the kind you draw circles with) and actually see what happens with a coil of wire, a battery, a resistor, and the compass.  Part of junior highschool physics used to involve building a voltmeter from such simple components.  It makes a world of difference to see how something works rather than just reading about it.

Comment: Thank you @JRE. So, I understand the for any voltage measurement, there needs to be a current provided to measure the voltage. Am I right?

Comment: **NO**.  The measuring device does **NOT** provide current.

Comment: @Newbie some voltage measureing devices do not draw a current at all, it is not necessary. However, most devices draw a tiny bit of current due to the way they happen to be implemented. That current could be below the pA level, though in the pA or nA is usually acceptable for most applications.

Comment: @Neil_UK, thank you. So, in that case, the current is taken from the DUT itself, right?

Comment: @Newbie Yes. So if the device being measured is a capacitor, it will steadily discharge into the voltage measuring device. In the bad old days, the only cheap voltage measuring devices were moving coil meters, which needed to draw 10s of micro-amps. Now, you can have a FET input follower which only draws 'leakage currents', sub pA easily. DVMs typically put a 10 M resistor across their inputs to get a predictable input resistance, which dominates any current the meter electronics draws.